# Center alignment of image inside flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have `img` and `a` inside `div` with `display: flex`.
 Looks like this:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div class="site-title-container">
    <img style="border-radius: 7px; width: 34px; height: 34px;" src="/assets/img/Icon-32@3x.png">  <!-- width="34" height="34" -->
    <a class="site-title" rel="author" href="{{ " / " | relative_url }}">{{ site.title | escape }}</a>
  </div>
 //.....
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   .site-title-container {
        float: left;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-content: center;
    }
```

Why can image still not be aligned to center?

Comment: can you use the built-in HTML/CSS/JS snippet to provide a demo?

Comment: remove the float

Comment: Float won't apply to a felx-child

Comment: What do you exactly want to align ? vertical ? --> https://jsfiddle.net/b5js0wzs/5/

Comment: It is `align-items`. And it wants to be set on the `parent`. All your `styles` you have. And keep `float` out. https://jsfiddle.net/dkcdszd8/7/.

Comment: I don't understand the reason of votes down :) do I luck something in my question?

Comment: @GuillaumeHarari, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `justify-content:center` for the main div.

```css
.site-title-container {
    float:left; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content:center">
  <div class="site-title-container">
    <img style="border-radius: 7px; width: 34px; height: 34px;" src="/assets/img/Icon-32@3x.png"> 
    <a class="site-title" rel="author" href="">{{ site.title | escape }}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `align-items: center` for the top-level `div` helped. could you please explain why it works, but doesn't for inner div?

Comment: Because your inner div does not cover 100% width. You can go with this solution or @Paulie_D solution. His solution will make your innerdiv width as 100%. So automatically that will work.

Comment: `Why can image still not be aligned to center?` This is what you have in your question.

Comment: vertically, not horizontally. sorry for not making it clear at first place

Comment: the issue was in `align-content` instead of `align-items`. changing this helped

Comment: yes..but that changes i did for `site-title-container`. In you earlier comment you have mentioned that changes did in top level. That's what i confused.

Comment: I think accepting your answer will be more fair then. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `.site-title-container` div collapses to the width of its contents when it becomes a flex-child

To make it expand to it's full width (100%) just apply `flex:1` to it.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.site-title-container {
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="site-title-container">
    <img style="border-radius: 7px; width: 34px; height: 34px;" src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300">
    <a class="site-title" rel="author" href="Some-Link">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as I mentioned in comments to @Suresh Ponnukalai answer, it centers it horizontally only

Comment: Fixed...check it out.

Comment: so stupid from my side. I had `align-content` instead of `align-items`. it was the issue in the first place

Answer (score 0):

```
.site-title-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).